# Objetos e Permanência em Memória em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, memória

É possível manter objetos em memória durante uma sessão no PHP ou é necessário usar a variável "session" para armazenar os objetos instanciados anteriormente?

O objetivo é criar um sistema web semelhante a uma aplicação OO convencional, só que no caso o servidor aguarda a resposta do usuário para modificar o estado dos objetos. Até onde eu entendi, a cada nova requisição será necessário recriar os objetos ao invés de mudar o estado dos que já existiam. Existe alguma forma de mantê-los em memória?

Comment: O que você entende por sessão nesse contexto?

Comment: Obrigado pelo interesse em responder a pergunta, Anderson! Sessão, início e fim definido de uma série de serviços. Minha ideia é implementar os serviços através de Objetos que ficariam disponíveis enquanto a sessão estiver iniciada pelo usuário, mas pelo que entendi das leituras que fiz antes de realizar esta pergunta é que não há uma forma de manter os objetos em memória enquanto aguardo interação do usuário.

Comment: Qual seria o motivo de você querer fazer isso?

Comment: Boa tarde, bfavaretto! Obrigado pelo comentário. O objetivo é criar um sistema web semelhante a uma aplicação OO convencional, só que no caso o servidor aguarda a resposta do usuário para modificar o estado dos objetos. Até onde eu entendi, a cada nova requisição será necessário recriar os objetos ao invés de mudar o estado dos que já existiam, o que para mim não parece algo prático ou interessante... Justamente por isso a pergunta.

Comment: @user3081078 que é um dos motivos de eu abominar o uso de OOP em PHP. Muito legal você ter tido essa preocupação, é por aí, acho que está começando a perceber uma coisa que infelizmente muita gente que "acha que entende" de PHP não parou pra pensar. Na maior parte dos casos, enquanto o código OOP está remontando o objeto que veio do script anterior, o código procedural já fez o que tinha que fazer e terminou faz tempo. Pegaram um conceito que veio de linguagens que mantém o estado, e aplicaram num engine de scripts, que por ironia... não mantém estado, o que é básico para justificar um objeto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Bacco! Fico feliz e triste ao mesmo tempo por saber que vou precisar trabalhar com serialização, já que a linguagem do sistema já foi estabelecida. Agradeço a contribuição!

Comment: Ou então pode usar PHP como ele foi concebido originalmente, tendendo para o procedural e deixando o OOP de lado :D - Provavelmente o código vai ficar, entre outras coisas, mais legível e absurdamente mais enxuto - lembrando que como a linguagem permite, você pode usar sem problemas os dois paradigmas conforme conveniência.

Comment: Não necessariamente com serialização. Você pode reinstanciar tudo a cada requisição. Não necessariamente serializar/desserializar vai te dar ganho de performance. Ou pode seguir a sugestão do @Bacco :)

Comment: Esses comentários do @Bacco deveriam ser um resposta, e daquelas canônicas bem destacadas

Comment: Você pode não querer "radicalizar" ao ponto da sugestão do @Bacco de abandonar OOP, mas não adianta querer fazer a aplicação funcionar da mesma maneira que em ambientes que mantêm estado. Na minha opinião, serializar o estado é a pior saída, a não ser que venha a resolver algum problema de desempenho que a aplicação esteja enfrentando.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pelas contribuições. Creio que vou ter que criar um mecanismo para serialização do estado dos objetos em que isso é necessário. Infelizmente preciso usar o PHP e, no momento, recriar todos os mecanismos que eu havia projetado vai demandar tempo que não tenho para o projeto! E concordo com o Maniero, os comentários do @Bacco com certeza serviram como resposta para minha pergunta.

Comment: Um último adendo, existe alguma linguagem web backend além do Java Server Pages que mantém o estado dos objetos criados? Fiquei com esta pulga atrás da orelha também com Python (Django) e Javascript (Node.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como esclarecido nos comentários da pergunta, a única forma de manter o estado dos objetos a cada requisição em PHP é salvando-os como variável de sessão.

Para continuar o desenvolvimento em Orientação a Objetos desenvolvi uma classe auxiliar chamada "Object Manager", que tem como função manter o estado dos objetos em sessão de forma simples.

Se tiverem curiosidade, é só [acessar aqui o projeto](https://github.com/igorVinicius/object-manager).

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram a esclarecer minhas dúvidas!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, usando as funções serialize() e unserialize() é possível armazenar objetos em $_SESSIONs. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
class UserTeste {
    private $nome = 'teste';
    public function getNome() {return $this->nome;}
}
$user = new UserTeste();
echo $user->getNome(); // teste

$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);

echo $_SESSION['user']; // O:9:"UserTeste":1:{s:15:"UserTestenome";s:5:"teste";}

$outroUser = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);

echo $outroUser->getNome(); // teste

?>
```

Usar serialize() codifica seus objetos para serem armazenado, só não esqueça de reverter a serialização com o unserialize() senão ocorrerá o mesmo que acontece no segundo echo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Dalabona! Mas há como manter o objeto em memória para utilizar a orientação a objetos sem utilizar a serialização? Esta é minha dúvida.. e creio que a resposta seja não.

Comment: Quando precisei usar em outros momentos, tive que usar o serialize. Não conheço outro método.

Comment: Perfeito Dalabona, valeu pela resposta!